# Refreshing activity after user changed location settings

Tags: android, onactivityresult

User flow: Clicks a button, is redirected to MapActivity where a google maps is shown. A location is given, there is a button to make a route using current location to the given location. When location services is turned off the user is prompted to turn it on.

```
private void goToLocationSettings(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: Log.e("test", "onActivityResult");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When the user returns the function should be able to complete. But the program again to turn the settings on. The log is never shown.

If I wait a bit after turning on location services on my device I do not get the question to turn it on, but the log message is still not shown.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are checking for the wrong `resultCode`, to avoid confusion use constants [Activity#RESULT_OK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) and [Activity#RESULT_CANCELED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_CANCELED). If you check the docs you can see that `RESULT_OK` has an int value of -1.

In the case of starting Location Settings Activity for result, the `resultCode` will always be 0 because the user exits the Settings Activity with a back button, so to the system it looks like he canceled the request.

```
static final int LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST = 1;

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST) {
         // user is back from location settings - check if location services are now enabled
         checkGPS();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Well that is interesting, if I run it with the debugger it appears the resultCode = 0, therefore it won't show the log if I place the Log there. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: You can not obtain a result from a location settings activity so the way to do it is to just check if the location services are now enabled when the user returns.

Comment: In this case `resultCode` will always be 0 because the user exits the Settings Activity with a back button, so it's as if he canceled the request.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box with out a result intent can be like this we need to allow the user to navigate and check the location services

accepted

In the case of starting Location Settings Activity for result, the resultCode will always be 0 because the user exits the Settings Activity with a back button, so to the system it looks like he canceled the request.

The code is here like which allow the dilog to navigate to setting page .

```
public void showLocationAlert() {
    if (!ismctLocationEnabled(this)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContentTransferBaseActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.mct_enable_Location_title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.mct_enable_location_message);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.mct_button_Enable,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.mct_button_Dismiss,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        if(!ismctLocationEnabled(this)) {
            alertDialog.show();
        }else
        {
            AlertDialog dialog=alertDialog.create();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}

public static boolean ismctLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {

        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

    } else {
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }
}
```